# PHP assign one array's values as a keys to another array's values if both arrays keys matches

Tags: php, arrays, array-key

```
<?php
echo '<pre>';

$directnames = array("LN"=>"ListingId","LAG"=>"AgentCode","ST"=>"MlsStatus","LP"=>"ListPrice","PIC"=>"PhotosCount");

$result = array("LN"=>"129_551453","LAG"=>"2.50","ST"=>"3.00","LP"=>"Ferndale","PIC"=>"359900.00");


$directnames_getkeys = array_keys($directnames);
$result_getkeys = array_keys($result);
$merge_keys = array_intersect($directnames_getkeys,$result_getkeys);
$assigning = array();

foreach($merge_keys as $preparevalues){
    foreach($directnames[$preparevalues] as $keys){
        echo $assigning[$keys] = $result[$preparevalues];
    }
}


echo '</pre>';
?>
```

**Expected output:**

```
array(
    "ListingId"=>"129_551453",
    "AgentCode"=>"2.50",
    "MlsStatus"=>"3.00",
    "ListPrice"=>"Ferndale",
    "PhotosCount"=>"359900.00"
    )
```

Comment: It says, it's an undeclared variable or argument passed on the line of second `foreach` for `$directnames` where you can see it's declared clearly.

Comment: when i run it, i get warning on line 16 that says Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() that's because $directnames[$preparevalues] is a STRING and not array

Comment: The `$directnames` is array. Do you mean `$preparevalues` should be an array?

Comment: no mate on second foreach you try to run a foreach on a string (the value of this $directnames[$preparevalues])

Comment: I think [array_combine](http://php.net/array_combine) also work for you http://ideone.com/zXUqov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `array_combine()`

```
$directnames = array("LN"=>"ListingId","LAG"=>"AgentCode","ST"=>"MlsStatus",
        "LP"=>"ListPrice","PIC"=>"PhotosCount");

         $result = array("LN"=>"129_551453","LAG"=>"2.50","ST"=>"3.00",
    "LP"=>"Ferndale","PIC"=>"359900.00");


            $a=array_combine($directnames,$result);
            print_r($a);
```

**output**:

Array ( [ListingId] => 129_551453 [AgentCode] => 2.50 [MlsStatus] => 3.00 [ListPrice] => Ferndale [PhotosCount] => 359900.00 )

Answer (score 0):

**This work fine:**

```
  $directnames = array("LN"=>"ListingId","LAG"=>"AgentCode","ST"=>"MlsStatus","LP"=>"ListPrice","PIC"=>"PhotosCount");

$result = array("LN"=>"129_551453","LAG"=>"2.50","ST"=>"3.00","LP"=>"Ferndale","PIC"=>"359900.00");


foreach($directnames as $value){
    $resultArray[][$value]= current($result);
    next($result);
}


var_dump($resultArray);
```

**Result:**

```
array(1) {
    ["ListingId"]=>
    string(10) "129_551453"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    ["AgentCode"]=>
    string(4) "2.50"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(1) {
    ["MlsStatus"]=>
    string(4) "3.00"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(1) {
    ["ListPrice"]=>
    string(8) "Ferndale"
  }
  [4]=>
  array(1) {
    ["PhotosCount"]=>
    string(9) "359900.00"
  }
```

Comment: I did the same before posting here, talking about what you have did above. Please see th expected output in the question. I appreciate your effort.

Comment: I dont unserstand, the result of my script is what you asked

Comment: You had applied a logic where each value is wrapped in an array.. Where as I was working for all values in one array..do you understand?